# How to write oracle sql to look for special characters

Tags: sql, regex, special-characters

I'm trying to search a varchar string for these specific characters.  `^$<>`  I tried using `regexp_like()`, but I can't figure out to only show the records that have those characters (since `^` and `$` are used to determine something else in that function).
My data is a title field - so I only want to see the titles that have any of those characters.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the regex pattern you tried along with a sample of the query?

Comment: You need to "escape" those chars in the pattern . i.e. \$  , etc.

Comment: Did you try `where col REGEXP_LIKE '[$^<>]'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
where col REGEXP_LIKE '[$^<>]'
```

Note that `^` is a negation marker when used as the first symbol inside a bracket expression, so it should be placed at the non-initial position.

Also, there is no need to add any `.*` to the pattern since `REGEXP_LIKE` is able to perform a partial match (i.e. there is no obligation to match the whole record).

Comment: this worked!  thank you - I think the issue I had was using ^ as the first item on the list.  This is my code, and it worked like a charm.  Thank you!  select ptcl_num, ptcl_title
from siebel.s_cl_ptcl_ls
where REGEXP_LIKE (ptcl_title,'[$`^<>]')
and  ptcl_num like ptcl_name